# log4j Exception handling

Tags: java, exception, log4j

I am new to Java World.

We have a Java application where it gives a specific type of exception. Is there any way, we can have log4j to react to specific way. Having own appender for something like MQ connection exception, we need to send email to specific group.

We are in the process of customizing a Java out of the application which intern uses MQ and through exception which we need to email.

I am actually looking for how the appender will look like

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're on the right track.  Implement your own Appender and only log things that match what you want to log.

Alternatively, use an existing appender (e.g. [SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html)) and implement/utilize an existing [Filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html) to limit what is sent there.

Comment: I think he is asking if he can catch the exception, and instead of log send email...

Comment: @Nix: Email is a form of logging, just like any other.  There's an SMTPAppender that sends out e-mail.

Comment: @MarkPeters what if the appender is asynchronous? will it always catch exception and send the email?

Comment: @guarav: The context might warrant a new question, but with logging frameworks they don't usually *catch* the exception, you as a developer catch the exceptions and then call something like `logger.error("XYZ operation failed", ex)`.  Then it's up to the log framework to know how to handle an exception passed to it for your logger and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to append an event only when it contains a certain class of exception, you could write a filter. Something along these lines (untested code!):

```
public final class ExceptionFilter extends org.apache.log4j.spi.Filter {

  private volatile String type;

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getType()
    return type;
  }

  public int decide(LoggingEvent evt) {
    Throwable t = evt.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable();
    if ((t != null) && t.getName().equals(type))
      return NEUTRAL;
    else
      return DENY;
  }

}
```